# how do I pull the first element out of each list inside a python list?

Tags: python, list

I have a a list with a nested list and inside that nested list is list of 15980 lists consisting of two numbers (which are probabilities from an `pytorch` model).  I need to iterate through unpack the 1st number from each list and make one series to append to a data frame.  I tried `[x for l in list for x in l]` but that just takes the 2nd nesting away and leaves a list of 15980 lists inside it.

Example:

```
a = [.22, .33]
b = [.23, .34]
c = [.76, .14]

d = [a,b,c]
e = [d]
```

`e` is what I'm working with. I need the first number out of a, b, and c to be put into a series.

Comment: Yes.  question edited

Comment: Does `e` always have just one element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple comprehension works:

```
[x[0] for x in d for d in e]
```

which evaluates to

```
[0.22, 0.23, 0.76]
```